# Why Custom Layout's modifer's height and width is applied to it's child? How to avoid it?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view, android-jetpack-compose

I've created a custom layout in jetpack compose to align the items in
a circular fashion. I have noticed something strange, or I don't know if I missed something from the android documentation. So, whenever I apply width and height or any of the either to modifier of the `Layout`. Its child items get that width or height. How should I avoid it, use it just apply to the parent but not child?
Here is the output.

[image: Screenshot of items when fillMaxWidth() is applied to the parent layout's modifier]
[image: Screenshot of items when I don't apply anything]
[image: what appear on phone]

Here is the code:

```
@Composable
fun CircularRevealMenu(
    modifier: Modifier,
    contentPadding: Dp = 16.dp,
    circleRadius: () -> Float,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    val configuration = LocalConfiguration.current

    Layout(content = content, modifier = modifier) { children, constraints ->
        val screenWidth = configuration.screenWidthDp.dp.toPx() * circleRadius()

        val placeables = children.map { it.measure(constraints) }

        val maxItemHeight = placeables.maxOf {
            it.height
        }
        val maxItemWidth = placeables.maxOf {
            it.width
        }

        val gap = 90 / placeables.size
        val radiusOffset = (max(maxItemHeight, maxItemWidth) / 2) + contentPadding.toPx()
        val radius = screenWidth - radiusOffset
        val offset = 180 - gap / 2f

        layout(screenWidth.toInt(), screenWidth.toInt()) {
            for (i in placeables.indices) {
                val radians = Math.toRadians((offset - (gap * i)).toDouble())
                placeables[i].placeRelative(
                    x = (cos(radians) * radius + screenWidth).toInt() - placeables[i].width / 2,
                    y = (sin(radians) * radius + 0).toInt() - placeables[i].height / 2
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

enum class CircularMenuStates { Collapsed, Expanded }

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun PreviewCircularMenu() {
    CircularRevealMenu(modifier = Modifier, circleRadius = { 1f }) {
        Text(text = "Item 1")
        Text(text = "Item 2")
        Text(text = "Item 3")
        Text(text = "Item 4")
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow. Please edit your question by adding a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: please share your code.

Comment: Have you tried providing separate width and height to the child

Comment: @RaBaKa78 yes even if I specifiy width & height to child it still takes whatever is specified for Layout.
And here is the code: https://gist.github.com/Jaseemakhtar/3746ce9dbbb28905658b0b2142ea2c54